# Unit test the thread safety of a singleton class in Java?

Tags: java, junit, thread-safety

Let's imagine I have the following java class :

```
static class Singleton {
    static Singleton i;

    static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (i == null) {
            i = new Singleton();
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Now, we all know this will work, but - it apparently is not thread safe - I am not actually trying to fix the thread safety - this is more of a demo, my other class is identical, but uses a mutex and synchronization - the unit test will be ran against each to show that one is thread safe, and the other, is not. What might the unit test which would fail if getInstance is not thread safe look like?

Comment: What aspect of it are you trying to test? If it's "exactly one instance will ever be created," that's not something a unit test can really do. You could write a test that starts a bunch of threads and has each one of them invoke `getInstance()`, and then check the instances you get back -- but even that is probabilistic at best, and likely won't hit the same conditions that you'll hit in real life (in terms of CPU usage, cache lines, etc). When it comes to checking for race conditions, unit tests are usually insufficient. That's one of the things that makes multithreading more difficult.

Comment: It might be hard to write a test that provokes an unsafe situation because you'd have to time 2 threads in a way that both enter the if-block simultaneously but one returns `i` before the other changes it. The problem is that you can't time threads in such a way, since when and how fast they run depends on a huge amount of things.

Comment: @yshavit - Yeah, thats why I cam to ask the question - I have had a bunch of thoughts on it, but I can't come up with anything deterministic!

Comment: I'd say writing a test that check for potentially unsafe situations requires  a good understanding on what could go wrong so that you can try to provoke those situations. However, once you understand the situations you're normally able to "prove" why they're dangerous and that they _can_ happen - in which case you'd not need the test anymore but should be able to fix the problem right away.

Comment: Create and start two threads which wait for a countdown latch before calling `getInstance()`; then count the latch down. You may have to run it many times (resetting i in between), but this is maybe the easiest way to exercise the race.

Comment: 1) javac 1.8.0_144: "Singleton.java:1: error: modifier static not allowed here: static class Singleton"? 2) Constructor not private? 3) instance `i` not private? "we all know this will work" - I don't *know* it yet, but I'd be really thankful if someone could share the knowledge since when such a thing counts as a singleton. Is it just "abstracted/simplified" because access modifiers are irrelevant for the question?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - "Let's imagine" - first two words of the question. This was never meant to be well written, it was to give someone enough to see my logic with getInstance() - and then help me with the unit test apprach.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds I guess what I'm saying is, the answer for "how do you unit test race conditions?" is usually "you don't." And I think that's the answer here, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, race conditions are by nature probabilistic so there's no deterministic way to truly generate a race condition. Any possible way against your current code would need to be run many times until the desired outcome is achieved. You can enforce a loose ordering of access on i by making a mock singleton to test against to simulate what a certain condition might look like, though. Rule of thumb with synchronization is preventative measures beat trying to test and figure out what's wrong after bad code is mangled in a code base.

```
static class Singleton {
    static Singleton i;

    static Singleton getInstance(int tid) {
        if (i == null) {

            if (tid % 2 == 0) i =  new Singleton()
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

So certain threads will write to i and other threads will read i as if they reached "return i" before "the even thread id's were able to check and initialize i" (sort of, not exactly, but it simulates the behavior). Still, there's a race between the even threads in this case because the even threads may still write to i after another reads null. To improve, you'd need to implement thread safety to force the condition where one thread reads i, gets null, while the other thread sets i to new Singleton() a thread-unsafe condition. But at that point you're better off just solving the underlying issue (just make getInstance thread safe!)

TLDR: there are infinitely many race conditions that can occur in a unsafe function call. You can mock the code to generate a mock of a specific race condition (say, between just two threads) but it's not feasible to just blanket test for "race conditions"

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.
The trick is that it is probabilistic like said by other users.
So, the approach that should be taken is to run for a number of times.

```
public class SingletonThreadSafety {

    public static final int CONCURRENT_THREADS = 4;

    private void single() {
        // Allocate an array for the singletons
        final Singleton[] singleton = new Singleton[CONCURRENT_THREADS];
        // Number of threads remaining
        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(CONCURRENT_THREADS);
        // Create the threads
        for(int i=0;i<CONCURRENT_THREADS;i++) {
            final int l = i; // Capture this value to enter the inner thread class  
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    singleton[l] = Singleton.getInstance();
                    count.decrementAndGet();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        // Ensure all threads are done
        // The sleep(10) is to be somewhat performant, (if just loop,
        //    this will be a lot slow. We could use some other threading
        //    classes better, like CountdownLatch or something.)
        try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
        while(count.get() >= 1) {
            try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
        for(    int i=0;i<CONCURRENT_THREADS - 1;i++) {
            assertTrue(singleton[i] == singleton[i + 1]);
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            Singleton.i = null;
            single();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This have to make some change in the Singleton design pattern. That the instance variable is now accessible in the Test class. So that we could reset the Singleton instance available to `null` again every time the test is repeated, then we repeat the test 1000 times (if you have more time, you could make it more, sometimes finding an odd threading problem require that).

Comment: Unfortunately - modifying the class in order to make this work is not really an option - we are testing for faults in the current spec.

Comment: There are some solutions to expose the private field for Unit testing. This solution didn't require any other change in your class except that the `instance` field must be exposable and settable in the test environment. https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-private-methods . The simplest thing is to use "reflection" to set the `instance` field (`i` in your example) to zero after each iteration

Comment: Small note, but do you know about CountDownLatch? You're using AtomicInteger basically as a replacement for it.

Comment: @yshavit This is only for simplicity.

Comment: @user9335240 Up to you, but I don't think two try-sleeps and a loop are simpler than `latch.await()` :)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this solution works. Unfortunately its hard to test singleton to provoke thread unsafe.

```
@Test
public void checkThreadUnSafeSingleton() throws InterruptedException {
    int threadsAmount = 500;
    Set<Singleton> singletonSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsAmount);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
            singletonSet.add(singleton);
        });
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Assert.assertEquals(2, singletonSet.size());
}
```